# How to notify the editor about document changes

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-extensions, vsix, vsx, vspackage

I work on a custom project system and I have an issue with renaming items. The project system implementation is based on MPF and renaming items via the solution explorer worked more or less without any problems, but...

When an item gets renamed, I also update information which are stored in the file itself. In case the document is opened by the code editor, the text in the editor doesn´t get refreshed (only the document window´s caption changes to the new filename). If I save the open document all changes applied by the rename operation are overriden, of course.

How can I force the editor to reload the document, so that the automatic changes will be shown?

Comment: How are you editing the file? Just changing the bits on disk or editing through some editor APIs?

Comment: I have an AST model that I can modify; so yes, I change the bits on disk...

Comment: The best thing to do is _not_ edit bits on disk, but edit the text through VS APIs. Forcing reloads isn't exactly nice if you can avoid it.

Comment: Got it; can you pinpoint to some documentation? What´s the best way to solve that kind of issue; I mean the document to rename can be  either opened in the editor, or not... how do I determine whether the document is opened; and if it´s open how should I interact with that window? What´s the recommended way to modify a document through VS APIs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it's a text file versus some custom designer, use the `IVsRunningDocumentTable` interfaces to get the text buffer for the file that's currently open. The [fourth iteration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsrunningdocumenttable4.aspx) of the interface is the easiest one to use from managed code. You can call `IsMonikerValid` (where the "moniker" is the file name) to see if the file is open, and if so then call `GetDocumentData` to get the `IVsTextBuffer` for the file. That type itself is fairly annoying to work with, so if you're only supporting Visual Studio 2010 or later, then pass that to [this function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.editor.ivseditoradaptersfactoryservice.getdocumentbuffer.aspx) to get the newer editor APIs version of it.

As far as they "why" it's a good idea to do this: if you edit the file on disk and then try to force a reload, there are various problems you might run into. If the file wasn't saved before the rename, you might accidentally lose those unsaved edits. The reload might cause the undo history of the file to be lost, and any other extensions/features that were tracking points in the file with editor tracking spans or markers might lose the points they're tracking. Performance should be a bit better too if the file is a large file.

Comment: `IVsRunningDocumentTable4` is only available in Visual Studio 2013, isn´t it? I probably need to work with `IVsRunningDocumentTable`.`GetDocumentInfo` instead, if I want support Visual Studio 2012 as well...

Comment: In that case, just use a lower-numbered-interface, with the caveat that you'll have to call some of the less friendly methods. Be _very_ careful with the ones that deal with IntPtrs. If you use them wrong you'll cause memory leaks.

Comment: I used `FindAndLockDocument` from `IVsRunningDocumentTable` and tried to safe-cast the result of `Marshal`.`GetObjectForIUnknown` to `IVsTextBuffer`. This works great. Finally, I release ppunkDocData as mentioned by the docs.

Comment: Once I had obtained an `ITextBuffer` from `IVsTextBuffer` applying changes was no big deal anymore. Thanks alot!